# Issues with importing CSV file into MySQL when comma in address

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm using a script that I found online to import CSV file into MySQL:  http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql but when the script detects a comma in an address like this `My address, CO 80113` in a cell, it also splits there as well.

I've seen a solution where you can save from excel to a Tab Delimited txt file.  Then you go into notepad and replace the tabs with semicolons.

Is this the best practice for "fixing the comma in the address" issue?

My end goal is to take a CSV file from Highrise full of hundreds of clients into our MySQL database, then make updates every couple of months so this seems to be a decent script but am I going at this the wrong way?

**EDIT :  It appears that the part of the PHP code that splits up the cells is this**

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use comma as column separator, then you should quote all string field values, e.g. -

```
1,'My address, CO 80113'
2,'His address, CO 80114'
4,'Her address, CO 80115'
and so on
```

Try to use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement with FIELDS **ENCLOSED BY** '\'' option.

Comment: Be aware, of course, that a quotation mark in an address is possible. Is there an "O'Neil Street" anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

comma (',') is the hart of CSV file so when you generate the csv file it divide cell when comma found.

So I think that you should replace the comma with the space or any other delimeter. you can use PHP 's default function **str_replace()** when your final code is generate for CSV.

Comment: I probably didn't explain well but if I do a str_replace() it will also replace the comma in the address.  Either way I can't simply replace a comma using PHP.  We export a CSV from Highrise and then i'd have to go from Excel and use a different delimeter that way I would imagine.  or no?

Comment: yes, you can but you can ally str_replace only on address field. what is mean by csv from highrise,,, actual I could not get this point.